# Rs485 DE signal, assertion time and deassertion time

Tags: stm32, assertion, stm32f4discovery, rs485

I want to send and receive data via rs485. I have a stm32 discovery that i connect to a device via rs485. So for transmit and receive I have to activate and deactivate  the DE, direction control line,

I don't understand the assertion time thing, it says that I should choose a assertion time and deassertion time based on the oversampling time, I have oversampling 16.

what I did instead, not using the Pin on mcu for rs485 function, but instead a random output pin that should(according to me :))work but it dosent, is that I did like this:

```
  while (1)
   {


HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB,SHDN_Linear_Pin,GPIO_PIN_SET);

HAL_UART_Transmit_IT(&huart1, (uint8_t *)bufftx ,strlen(bufftx));
HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart1, buffrx, 10);
HAL_Delay(1000);
 /* USER CODE END WHILE */

 /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */

 }
```

The WritePin function works when I do SET, and it sends the data, after that it should go to the function below and RESET the PIN so that I can receive, but it does not RESET. Maybe I have to use a delay, I will test that.

```
/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */
 void HAL_UART_TxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart)
  {
  /* Prevent unused argument(s) compilation warning */
  UNUSED(huart);

  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB,SHDN_Linear_Pin,GPIO_PIN_RESET);

 /* NOTE : This function Should not be modified, when the callback is needed,
        the HAL_UART_TxCpltCallback could be implemented in the user file
   */ 
  }
  /* USER CODE END 4 */
```

But is this a good way doing it, can any one please explain how I should use assertion time instead? Is what I did fast enough for the DE line to go low before the data is sent?

```
  HAL_StatusTypeDef HAL_RS485Ex_Init
      (UART_HandleTypeDef * huart, uint32_t Polarity, uint32_t
      AssertionTime, uint32_t DeassertionTime
```

this is what the usermanual for the hal library says one should use, Should I use  it the same way I did within the callback function?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Firstly**, you should remember that RS485 is half-duplex interface, you can't transmit     and recive data simultaneous. You are use unblocked fuinctions(transfer by IT) so this code is incorrect:

```
while (1)
{
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB,SHDN_Linear_Pin,GPIO_PIN_SET);

    HAL_UART_Transmit_IT(&huart1, (uint8_t *)bufftx ,strlen(bufftx));
    HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart1, buffrx, 10);
    HAL_Delay(1000);
}
```

You should check TX status before receive or use blocked fuinction like `HAL_UART_Transmit`

```
while (1)
{
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB,SHDN_Linear_Pin,GPIO_PIN_SET);

    g_is_tx_complete = false;
    HAL_UART_Transmit_IT(&huart1, (uint8_t *)bufftx ,strlen(bufftx));

    while(!g_is_tx_complete)
    {

    }

    HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart1, buffrx, 10);
    HAL_Delay(1000);
}
```

**Secondly,** as I undestand you don't receive TX Complete interrupt. I didn't see all code but you shold enable interrpt by NVIC and control registers like here:

```
/* Enable RXNE interrupt */
USART_ITConfig(USART1, USART_IT_RXNE | USART_IT_TXC, ENABLE);
/* Enable USART1 global interrupt */
NVIC_EnableIRQ(USART1_IRQn);
```

and if you use `HAL_UART_TxCpltCallback` HAL handler, you should make sure the`USART1_IRQHandler` call the `HAL_USART_IRQHandler` function

```
void USART1_IRQHandler(void)
{
    HAL_USART_IRQHandler(&huart1);
}
```